# WCF REST Streaming for video playback

Tags: wcf, flash, html, video, streaming

I need to play videos on the ASP MVC 4 web site with HTML5 video tag, if supported, or JW Player otherwise. Now I use WCF REST method to get access to video files in the following way:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
    public Stream Download(string id, bool isTemp)
    {
        //File.OpenRead(path) works inside FileBlo.Fownload 
        Stream download = FileInfoBlo.Download(id, isTemp);
        if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
        {
            //Specifing any other mime type doesn't help
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "video/*";
        }
        return download;
    }
```

So the link to the file is like

> > http://localhost/app-api/Apiservice.svc/download?id=8&isTemp=false

The problems are:

1. HTML5 playback - only Chrome can play video, but can't do anyhing else - stop, play again, seek etc. Other browsers don't play it at all. When accessing the file with just a link to the file like

> > "http://localhost/app/file.mp4"

it can be played.

2. JW PLayer playback - error happens -

> > an error ask Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist file did not contain a valid playlist

when accessing the file with link (as shown above) - it can play it at least.

As I understand such kind of "wcf streaming" is not suitable for video playback. 
May be WCF is not an option here at all?
So any help and advices\examples of proper video streaming whithin IIS (7+ / Server 2008) will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the response headers. Specifically:
Content-Range
X-Content-Duration
Content-Length